# cakephp .htaccess configuration on godaddy with subdomain

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have one domain on godaddy (www.mydomain.com). I have placed my cakephp application on this domain. It is working fine for me.

But i have created a subdomain blog.mydomain.com for this godaddy has created a directory named blog inside the www.mydomain.com now how can i redirect the request coming for blog.mydomain.com to the blog/ folder.

I am trying this,

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog.mydomain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ blog/$1    [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com/$
RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
```

It works for single Rewrite condition like,

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog.mydomain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ blog/$1    [L]
```

But when i add another rewrite condition for my cake app it shows 500 Internal server error for blog.mydomain.com

Please help me out .............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the blog folder in webroot (under your cake directory) and it should work just fine. Or did you need to do something else more fancy?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://digitalmemo.neobie.net/2011/04/19/cakephp-bypassing-for-subdomain/

It use to make all the subdomains to be working correctly instead of defining each of the subdomain.